# Git: How to move contents of gh-pages branch to docs/ directory preserving history?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

So [github recently implemented a feature to use the `docs/` directory of `master` instead of `gh-pages`](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/). And this is good for some use cases, such as mine.

The scenario is a git repo with a `master` and a `gh-pages` branch (the "old" way of doing github pages), and I want to move everything in the `gh-pages` branch to the `docs/` directory in `master` (the "new" way of doing github pages).

I'm aware I can use `git checkout master; git checkout gh-pages -- docs`, but this will remove history from the `gh-pages` files, which is undesired.

I have fiddled around with `git subtree` and `git filter-branch`, with no success.

So the question is: *Is there a magic one-liner `git` command to move the contents of another branch into a subdirectory while keeping history?*

Comment: I didn't realize that this was the "new" cool way of doing things?

Answer (score 2):

`git subtrees` are perfect for this. You mentioned you "fiddled" with them, but did you try:

```
git subtree add --prefix=docs origin gh-pages
```

Check out my [`docs-subtree` branch](https://github.com/admonkey/Leaflet/tree/docs-subtree)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a one-line command, but you could try a rebase, and then merge it into *master*:

```
git checkout gh-pages
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff gh-pages
```

Comment: I did try that, with a `git mv * docs/` first. But the branching of `gh-pages` dates back to 2011 and the merge conflict is *humongous*.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any magic one-liner, but doing a `git merge` (thanks @Wikiti for inspiring me towards trying that option once again) seemed to work.

The final method I followed is not pretty, and involves running `git reset` a number of times.

**This is not perfect, and I encourage any git experts or gitlab employees to suggest better solutions.** In the hopes it will help others trying to move away from a `gh-pages` branch, this is how I did it:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b master-docs
git merge gh-pages

# Reset the "master" files so that files deleted are left untouched by the merge
git reset src/
git checkout src/
git reset any-other-master-files
git checkout any-other-master-files

# Manually edit any conflicts, e.g. in .gitignore (with your favourite editor)
vi .gitignore
git add .gitignore
vi any-other-conflicting-files
git add any-other-conflicting-files

# Move the "gh-pages" files into "docs/" directory
mkdir docs
git mv *.md docs/
git mv *.html docs/
git mv _posts docs/
git mv _layout docs/
git mv any-other-gh-pages-files docs/

# Check that everything looks OK, there should be only files added to docs/
# If not, go through last steps again
git status

# Confirm the merge
git commit

# Push to origin
git push -u master-docs

# Go to github, make a pull req from master-docs to master for peer review
```

(The [result doesn't look bad](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4826) )